# Export map with single point feature over many features in feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, feature-class, data-driven-pages

I have a feature class with > 7,000 point features and ~ 2,500 unique ID's (integers). I need to create simple map print outs for each of the unique ID's all with the same zoom extents. I've been looking into Data Driven pages, but it seems like that wont do because I can't figure out how to have each page contain only points associated with a particular unique ID. Is this something I can do in DDP or should I write something with ArcPy?

Comment: To clarify, you don't want the extent to change, but for each map you want only features with the same ID?

Comment: That is correct. In the end, there should be ~2,500 map exports all this same extent.

Comment: This is something you could do with Data Driven Pages with a little effort (although not difficult).  If you know arcpy it might be easier to do in arcpy - have you tried that?  If so can you include what you've tried?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to create a page definition query as explained on this [ESRI help page on Page Definition queries](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/using-page-definition-queries.htm) . You'll also need to get the extent not moving.

I'll enrich this answer as soon as I have access to Arcgis (probably on friday) to give the exact way of doing it, but that's a first quick answer from memory.

> How to create a Page Definition Query
>
> - Right-click the layer in the table of contents and click Properties. Do not attempt this with the Data Driven Pages index layer, as Page Definition Queries are not supported for the current index layer. (*RobinP's tip : you'll probably need to duplicate your layer and freeze the index layer*)
> - Click the Definition Query tab on the Layer Properties dialog box.
> - Click the Page Definition button.
> - Click the Enable check box.
> - Select the field that matches the Data Driven Pages Page name field from the Page Name Field drop-down list.
> - Choose to show either features that Match or Don't Match the page.
> - Click OK.

Comment: +1 This is what I would have answered.  May need to create a static extent to use as index layer otherwise the extent may change for each ID.